# App not showing same result as Xcode simulator

Tags: xcode, macos, nstableview, nscalendar

I am new to Xcode and app programming and developed a small app to get certain calendar events and present them in a NSTableview.
The program is working fine in my Xcode simulator.
However when I build for running and start the App on my iMac, is is not returning any calendar events. Just runs and ends without any errors.
What am I missing here?

Comment: You say your app is written for OS X but you also say you're running in a simulator.  Those concepts don't usually go together.  What simulator do you mean?

Comment: Sorry Philip. I wrote the App in Xcode and tested it inside Xcode. That is what I meant with "simulator".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by adding `[store requestAccessToEntityType:(EKEntityTypeEvent) completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)` after the allocation of the EKEventStore.